# java android gallery image import

Tags: java, android, image, android-gallery

So I'm working on a project that will take in an image from the android gallery, open it in the imageview, and display a bunch of statistics for image quality assessment. These stats include brightness, sharpness, image orientation, and contrast, which all seem to be working. Currently I have it working with a folder titled "assets" that has a bunch of images. I'm trying to modify it so that I can scroll through the internal asset images in the build, but ALSO take in new images from gallery and display the statistics for them as well. This is going to be used for facial recognition, and the scores will help the user decide if the image is adequate enough based on these stats.

Attached is my current main activity code, and I've tried a bunch of things, but I can't seem to get this to work. If you need any more info let me know, I'm new to android, java, and stack overflow! Any help appreciated!

Edit: I seem to run into issues with permissions (which seems to be related to sdk 23?) But I've gone back and forth with code, adding it, deleting it and nothing seems to give me the correct way to pull an image from gallery. For most of the situations I've tried the app will crash either while OPENING gallery(onclick), or while trying to pull the image from gallery (clicking image after gallery is already open). I've removed all the code I've tried related to the gallery because none of it was working. If you need more info let me know!

```
package com.example.matthew.imagequalityassessment;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;


import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.media.FaceDetector;

import java.util.Vector;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static final String IMAGE_TYPE = "image/*";
private static final int SELECT_SINGLE_PICTURE = 101;


int count = 0;

/* The file index */
int imgIdx = 0;

/* The list of files */
Vector<String> files = new Vector<String>();


/* Get the reference to the image object */
ImageView imageView = null;

/* Get the reference to the text label */
TextView label = null;

/* By how much to scale down the original image.
 * During tests, I sometimes had to scale down
 * the image size, as some old phones ran out
 * of memory.
 */
final int IMAGE_SCALE_DOWN_FACTOR = 2;

/**
 * Displays the next image
 * @param image - the image to show
 * @param fileName - the name of the image file
 */




void showImage(Bitmap image, String fileName)
{

    label.setText("Loading...");

    /* Get the starting time */
    long startTime = 0;

    startTime = System.nanoTime();

    /* Get the image statistics */
    ImageStats imageStats = new ImageStats(image);

    System.out.println("Execution time: " + (((double)(System.nanoTime() - startTime))/1000000000.0) + " seconds!");

     /* Get the image statistics */
    double[] stats = imageStats.getStats();

    /*  Decide whether or not the image is of good quality */
    String results = imageStats.result;

     /* Create the labels */
    String[] labels = new String[]{"Standard Luminosity: ", "Contrast: ", "Face orientation: ", "Sharpness: "};

     /* The string of statistics */
    StringBuffer strStatsBuff = new StringBuffer();

     /* Go through all the statistics */
    for(int statIndex = 0; statIndex < stats.length; ++statIndex)
    {
          /* Add the statistics */
        strStatsBuff.append(labels[statIndex]);
        strStatsBuff.append(String.valueOf(stats[statIndex]));
        strStatsBuff.append("\n");
    }

     /* Add the file name */
    strStatsBuff.append("File name: ");
    strStatsBuff.append(fileName);
    strStatsBuff.append("\n");
    strStatsBuff.append(results);


      /* Set the label and show the image */
    label.setText(strStatsBuff.toString());
    imageView.setImageBitmap(image);

}


/**
 * Reads the bitmap image from the assets library
 * @param fileName - the file name
 * @return - The loaded image
 */
Bitmap loadBitmapFromAssets(String fileName)
{

    /* The bitmap */
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    /* Load the image */
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Trying to load file <" + fileName + "> from assets");

        /* Load the image */
        InputStream input = getAssets().open(fileName);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth()/IMAGE_SCALE_DOWN_FACTOR, bitmap.getHeight()/IMAGE_SCALE_DOWN_FACTOR, false);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("Something went wrong...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bitmap;
}


/**
 * This is where the program execution begins
 * @param savedInstanceState - the instance of the application.
 */

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    /* Call the constructor of the super-class */
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button buttonGallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGallery);





    /* Get the asset manager */
    AssetManager am = getAssets();


    /* Populate the file list */
    try {

        for(String s: am.list(""))
        {
            if(s.endsWith(".jpg") || s.endsWith(".png"))
            {
                files.add(s);

            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /* Get the reference to the image object */
    imageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    /* Get the reference to the text label */
    label = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label);


      /* Get the reference to the "next" button */
    Button buttonNext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);

      /* Shows the next image when the "next" button is clicked */
    buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
                /* No files to show */
            if(files.size() == 0) return;

                /* Increment the index */
            ++imgIdx;

                /* Is this the end of the list? Go back to the beginning */
            if(imgIdx == files.size())
                imgIdx = 0;

                /* Load the bitmap */
            Bitmap bitmap = loadBitmapFromAssets(files.get(imgIdx));

            System.out.println("Image width: "+ bitmap.getWidth());

                /* Show the image */
            showImage(bitmap, files.get(imgIdx));

        }
    });



      /* Get the reference to the "Previous" button */
    Button buttonPrev = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonPrev);

      /* Shows the next image when the "next" button is clicked */
    buttonPrev.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
                    /* No files to show */
            if(files.size() == 0) return;

                    /* Is this the end of the list? Go back to the beginning */
            if(imgIdx == 0)
                imgIdx = files.size() - 1;
                    /* Otherwise, increment the index */
            else
                        /* Decrement the index */
                --imgIdx;

                    /* Load the bitmap */
            Bitmap bitmap = loadBitmapFromAssets(files.get(imgIdx));

                    /* Show the image */
            showImage(bitmap, files.get(imgIdx));


        }

    });



      /* Load the first image */
    if(files.size() != 0)
    {
         /* Load the first image */
        showImage(loadBitmapFromAssets(files.get(0)), files.get(0));
    }
}

}
```

This is what I have so far, and the search gallery button crashes
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcCEY.png

Comment: "I've tried a bunch of things, but I can't seem to get this to work" -- what is "this"? What does "can't seem to get this to work" mean? Please edit your question and provide *specific* problems with *specific* symptoms.

Comment: Agreed with @CommonsWare,  also if a particular error is being thrown put a trace of it. Also everything CPU intensive must be in another thread so wrap it in an AsyncTask if possible.